# Accessing private value in array, converted from object

Tags: php

I have this little code:

```
class A
{
    private $val  = 5;
}

$a = new A();
$obj = (array)$a;
echo '<pre>'; var_dump ($obj); echo '</pre>';
echo $obj['Aval']; // error!
```

after dumping $obj, the result is:

```
array(1) {
  ["Aval"]=>
  int(5)
}
```

but accessing this value with $obj['Aval']; triggers an error - thats impossible!

Comment: Private object properties cast to an array have null byte characters in the property name

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have a look at the [documentation on converting to an array](http://nz1.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting), it states:

> private variables have the class name prepended to the variable name; protected variables have a '*' prepended to the variable name. These prepended values have null bytes on either side.

This means that it's not `A` that's prepended, but `\0A\0`. So the key would be `"\0A\0val"`.

Comment: alright, I modified to "echo $obj["\0A\0Aval"]; // error!" and still the same error (Php 5.4)

Comment: @JohnSmith not echo correctly. using two times `A`. try this `echo $obj["\0A\0val"];`

Comment: Try `$key = 0x00 . 'A' . 0x00 . 'val'; echo $obj[$key];`

Comment: somehow "echo $obj[0x00 . 'A' . 0x00 . 'val']; " -> error: Undefined index: 0A0val in

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code. It works.

```
class A {
    private $val  = 5;
}

$a = new A();
$obj = (array)$a;
echo '<pre>'; print_r ($obj); echo '</pre>';
echo $obj["\0A\0val"];
```

The error is because of the null bytes on either side.

Answer (score 1):

This code is tested:

```
class a
{
  private $x = "something";
}

$w = new a();

print_r($w); // object

print_r((array)$w); // cast as array
```

And this is the result:

```
a Object ( [x:a:private] => something ) Array ( [ax] => something ) // the print_r result
```

So what has happened literally is that the name of the class (string) is prepended to the variable name, which makes `x` to be `ax`.

Though, as already suggested, to access the property, you have to:

```
$arrayed = (array)$w;

var_dump($arrayed["\0a\0x"]);
```

Adding a `\0` before and after the class name and prepending the concatenated string all to the key name you want to access.